# C++ byte const* write to file

Tags: c++

I'm receiving the following as an argument in a callback function in C++.

byte const* Buffer()

The Buffer is a pointer to a buffer containing video frame.
How can I save that to a file?

Thanks

Comment: Open a file stream, write data to it & then close the file stream, If you need to ask the steps, What you really need is to pick up a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

The pointer shows that C solution will be more appropriate:

```
FILE * videoFile;
byte buffer*; //you already received it
int buffer_len; // you receive that too
videoFile = fopen ( "myvideo.mp4" , "wb" );
fwrite (buffer , 1 , buffer_len , videoFile);
fclose (videoFile);
```

Comment: Why would you provide a `C` solution to a `C++` Question?

Comment: C++ question featuring pointers? Hmm. It seems like the question is not that C++ after all...

Comment: @Als people frequently don't strictly differentiate between C and C++ when they look for answers. I see nothing wrong with a C answer to a C++ question (that's not really C++ to begin with).

Comment: I hate this "if you write C++, you'd better use every single C++ feature in the spec" mentality. C++ isn't a superset of C just for the hell of it.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: I can only just hope with time You will learn to judge better. Peace :)

Comment: Also this is obviously C++ code. Just look at the comments :P

Comment: Thanks it works although I can't fig it out the format it sending.... meaning I can't open the file saved.

Comment: You just receive the bytes and save them as they are to a file. The only thing that might be failing you is if the extension I specified is not the correct one. Please choose appropriate extension (e.g. avi, mp4 etc).